# How is Java String constructor implemented?

Tags: java, string

I was going through Java String source code, found a CTOR where I have some doubts:

```
public String(String original) {
    this.value = original.value;
    this.hash = original.hash;
}
```

I understood that Original is acting as literal `String` (with double quotes) but not able to understand how is java/jvm computed `original.value` as `char` Array. What is "value" over here?? if value is `char` Array then how `.value` function/Field is calculated???

Comment: What do you mean by "dot value function"? `original.value` is simply an instance field of type `char[]` in the original String.

Comment: As you are looking at the source code of `String`, you can understand that the `String class` of `Java` is actually implemented with a char array, which is the `value` you saw, a field of the class, nothing to surprise.

Comment: You are correct, `new String ("newstring")`, here we are trying to create `String` object but "newString" already acting as `String` object, how???

Comment: `"newstring"` (and every other string literal, as well)  _acts as_ a `String` because it **is a `String`**.

Comment: Kevin, just want to understand how JVM make each String literal as String object internally???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String by design holds Unicode text, so all language scripts may be combined.
For that the implementation holds an array (field name `value`), where every char is a two byte UTF-16 value.

You encountered the one and AFAIK only silly point in the Java classes.

The shown *copy constructor* is senseless, as Strings are immutable objects,
and they may be shared by simple assignment. It is a fossile of C++ inheritance,
maybe in association with String interning.

To make a *copy* is senseless. This holds too for the internal `char` array, which indeed may be assigned by reference. (Not very consequent.)

So the following shows inexperienced java usage:

```
String s = new String(t);
```

With the newest java versions, the value of a String might actually be a byte array in some encoding, and hence the chars are lazily provided.

---

***About String literals:***

String literals are stored in a datastructure in a .class file called the *constant pool*. Stored is it as UTF-8 bytes. The JVM ClassLoader ensures that the string is loaded as String.

Imports of `final static String` constants are copied into the constant pool, and the original class may no longer appear as being imported from.
Holding string constant in an other class may require manually doing a clean build, as there might no longer exist a class dependency.

Comment: Basically, I would agree. But while `s=t` means also that `s==t` is true, the consequence of `s=new String(t)` has the effect that the same comparison is now false ('==', not `equals()`). As said in the documentation: "[…] Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary […]" – Ok, I have not encountered the need for an explicit copy of a String, only when playing around with JNI, but the limited usefulness is mentioned and makes the whole thing less silly.

Comment: @Iquadrat I can only imagine the use in combination with `String.#ntern()`, Something for an annation `@Esoteric public String(String original) ...`

Comment: The documentation says about `intern()`: "[…] It follows that for any two strings `s` and `t`, `s.intern() == t.intern()` is true if and only if `s.equals( t )` is true. […]" – So combining `new String()` with `intern()` does not make sense in my eyes – or I miss some important point here.

Comment: it is very close to answer but nobody gave me answer on this, "Just want to understand how JVM make each String literal as String object internally???"

Comment: @AbhiS okay added a section. As the ClassLoader loads the constant pool with string literals, stored there by the compiler, it has little to do with the JDK sources.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as already mentioned in the comments, this is very simple.
Since you're looking at the `String` class itself — it has access to its own fields. And that is where the characters this given string consists of are actually stored — in a `char` array. This method simply references the field by name, very basic interaction.

Comment: Correct!!! Just want to understand how JVM make each String literal as String object internally???

Comment: @AbhiS You should in general ask more specific questions here, general questions like  "what is all this" are often considered too broad or irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-java.lang.String-) says

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the
>   same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly
>   created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit
>   copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary
>   since Strings are immutable.

Technically the new String will get the `value` and `hash` of the `original`.

[image]

which means that this is a copy of another String.